# Clients synchronization during streaming

Tags: synchronization, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, rtp

During any streaming, for proper playback of streams at the clients a timestamp is necessary. I have also seen certain protocols including a 32-bit timestamp field in their headers. But before doing this, the clocks of the interacting clients have to be synchronized, otherwise one of the clocks will lag/lead from the other and the timestamp sent in the packets may not make any sense at all. Time sync is usually done using a time server and both the clients pull the time from this server and set their clocks accordingly. During a video chat, say via Skype or Google chat, are the client clocks actually synchronized or do they synchronize using a different approach? Because, if the clients are synchronized using a time server, the system clock has to change everytime i have a chat with someone.

Answer (score 0):

> During any streaming, for proper playback of streams at the clients a timestamp is necessary.

This is not accurate.  Why would you think timestamps are necessary?  Simply playback data as it arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You need timestamps for lipsync and jitter buffer, usually timestamps relative to the start of the session.

Save start of your session as time zero. Start receiving media packets and putting in jitter-buffer showing loading sign on the screen. When jitter buffer covers some time span start playing media packets according to their timestamps. Send reports back to server about your jitter buffer state, so if your network doesn't provide required speed server can skip short period of the session or reduce data amount.

That's described in details in [RTP protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol)